# Getting column names based on several conditions using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    c1  e  c2   d   s  scr_s  scr_c1  scr_d  scr_c2  scr_e  r1     r2
12  6   13  3   2   11    22      19      5       5     19  scr_s  scr_d    
13  11  2   6   13  3      9      24     15       9     13  scr_c1 scr_s
```

I'm trying to get the name of the column evaluating max and min value for the columns *scr_s, scr_c1, scr_d, scr_c2, scr_e.* So the column name with highest value will be store in *r1* and the column name with lowest value will be store in *r2*

To calculate r1 and r2, I'm using:

```
data['r1'] = data[['scr_s','scr_c1','scr_d','scr_c2','scr_e']].idxmax(axis=1)
data['r2'] = data[['scr_s','scr_c1','scr_d','scr_c2','scr_e']].idxmin(axis=1)
```

**Problem**: when two columns have the *same max or min values*, I have to select the column name that have the *max value* in one of this columns *'c1','e','c2','d','s'*

In this particular case, when analyzing column r2, the result should be different:

- For the first row, columns *scr_d* and *scr_c2* share the same min value, so column *'d' and 'c2'*, should be evaluated. Between column *'d and c2'*, the highest value belongs to *'c2'*, so the expected result for *r2* is *scr_c2*.

How can I solve this problem?

**Expected output:**

```
    c1  e  c2   d   s  scr_s  scr_c1  scr_d  scr_c2  scr_e  r1     r2
12  6   13  3   2   11    22      19      5       5     19  scr_s  *scr_c2*  
13  11  2   6   13  3      9      24     15       9     13  scr_c1 *scr_c2*
```

Comment: Try: `data['r1'] = data[['scr_s','scr_c1','scr_c2','scr_d','scr_e']].idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: I have hundreds of observations, so changing the order won't help.

Comment: How do the *observations* (column names) look like? Are they all `scr_cxxx` and `scr_d`? How do you rank their importance?

Comment: By observations I meant samples, sorry. The problem is that I have to compare columns  `c1, e,  c2,   d,   s` in order to pick the 'winner'

Comment: Then why you expected second entry for `r2` is `scr_c2`?

Comment: Please @Pepe also consider my approach since it should be easy when more than 2 elements are equal. You just add a condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Create lists of relatively related column names

```
base = ['c1', 'e', 'c2', 'd', 's']
extd = [f'scr_{c}' for c in base]
```

#### Create lists of tuples of those columns

```
base_tups = [*zip(*map(df.get, base))]
extd_tups = [*zip(*map(df.get, extd))]
```

#### Zip those tuples together

```
zvals = [[*zip(*t)] for t in zip(extd_tups, base_tups)]
```

It looks like this

```
[[(19, 6), (19, 13), (5, 3), (5, 2), (22, 11)],
 [(24, 11), (13, 2), (9, 6), (15, 13), (9, 3)]]
```

#### Set up for a `idxmax`/`idxmin` type thing

```
r = range(len(base))

rvals = {}

rvals['r1'] = [extd[max(r, key=lambda i: x[i])] for x in zvals]
# flip sign on second element to get what OP wants v
rvals['r2'] = [extd[min(r, key=lambda i: (x[i][0], -x[i][1]))] for x in zvals]

df.assign(**rvals)

    c1   e  c2   d   s  scr_s  scr_c1  scr_d  scr_c2  scr_e      r1      r2
12   6  13   3   2  11     22      19      5       5     19   scr_s  scr_c2
13  11   2   6  13   3      9      24     15       9     13  scr_c1  scr_c2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start like this:

- Create the list of elements you check
- Find the max
- If there are 2 elements with same max value check deeper.
- Else return the string that we write to `r1` or `r2`

---

```
def fmax(r, ind):
    l=[]    
    for i in ind:
        l.append(r[i])        
    m = max(l)
    nl=[i for i, j in enumerate(l) if j == m]
    if(len(nl)==2):        
        e1=ind[nl[0]] 
        e2=ind[nl[1]] 
        e1=e1.replace('scr_','') # element 1
        e2=e2.replace('scr_','') # element 2
        if(r[e1]> r[e2]):
            return 'scr_'+e1
        else:
            return 'scr_'+e2
    else:
        return ind[l.index(max(l))] #returns single max




def fmin(r, ind):
    l=[]    
    for i in ind:
        l.append(r[i])        
    m = min(l)
    nl=[i for i, j in enumerate(l) if j == m]
    if(len(nl)==2):        
        e1=ind[nl[0]] 
        e2=ind[nl[1]] 
        e1=e1.replace('scr_','') # element 1
        e2=e2.replace('scr_','') # element 2
        if(r[e1]> r[e2]):
            return 'scr_'+e1
        else:
            return 'scr_'+e2
    else:
        return ind[l.index(min(l))] #retuns single min


df['r1']= df.apply(lambda r: fmax(r, ['scr_s','scr_c1','scr_d','scr_c2','scr_e']), axis=1)
df['r2']= df.apply(lambda r: fmin(r, ['scr_s','scr_c1','scr_d','scr_c2','scr_e']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

---

```
    c1   e  c2   d   s  scr_s  scr_c1  scr_d  scr_c2  scr_e r1 r2
12   6  13   3   2  11     22      19      5       5     19  .  .
13  11   2   6  13   3      9      24     15       9     13  .  .
    c1   e  c2   d   s  scr_s  scr_c1  scr_d  scr_c2  scr_e      r1      r2
12   6  13   3   2  11     22      19      5       5     19   scr_s  scr_c2
13  11   2   6  13   3      9      24     15       9     13  scr_c1  scr_c2
```